# Does $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)$ converges conditionally?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I'm trying to understand whether the following series converges absolutely, conditionally or diverges.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)
$$

I think that it converges conditionally. But it's getting complicated for me to show that it does not converge absolutely. I've already tried the limit comparison test with $b_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ but the limit results in $0$. I've also tried the integral test, as the conditions for the test hold, but the integral became very complicated.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Try $b_n = \frac 1n$.

Comment: Thank you, worked out fine with $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @AlonWeissfeld Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)= \frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n\sqrt n}\right)$$

then the given series doesn’t converge absolutely by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n}$ and then

$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{n+1} \frac1{2n}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{n+1} O\left(\frac1{n\sqrt n}\right)
$$

which converges since

- $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{n+1} \frac{1}{2n}$ converges by alternating series test
- $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(-1\right)^{n+1} O\left(\frac1{n\sqrt n}\right)$ converges absolutely by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n\sqrt n}$

Comment: The last series converges absolutely by the comparison test, not limit comparison.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Why limit comparison test shouldn't work?

Comment: $$\left| \left(-1\right)^{n+1} O\left(\frac1{n\sqrt n}\right) \right| \leq M \frac1{n\sqrt n}$$ this doesn't say anything else, so you cannot apply limit comparison test. Just the usual comparison test.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Why this $$\frac{\left| \left(-1\right)^{n+1} O\left(\frac1{n\sqrt n}\right) \right|}{ \frac1{n\sqrt n}} \to L \leq M$$ doesn't work?

Comment: You have absolutely no way to know whether the limit $\lim_n \frac{\left| \left(-1\right)^{n+1} O\left(\frac1{n\sqrt n}\right) \right|}{ \frac1{n\sqrt n}}$ exists ! Just because $u_n\leq M v_n$ doesn't imply that $\lim_n \frac{u_n}{v_n}$ exists. All you can say is $\limsup_n \frac{u_n}{v_n} \leq M$, but that's enough to prove convergence of the series.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Then to use limit comparison test we should refer to little-o? and write $$\frac{\left| \left(-1\right)^{n+1} o\left(\frac1{n^\frac54}\right) \right|}{ \frac1{n^\frac54}} \to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), we see that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\left( 1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)$ converges.

From Taylor series we have
$$\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \leq 1-\frac{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2}{2} + \frac{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^4}{24}= 1-\frac{1}{2n} + \frac{1}{24n^2}\quad \text{for $n\geq 1$}$$
Therefore, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\cos\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \right)\geq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2n} -\frac{1}{24n^2}\right)= \infty$$
So, the series fails to converge absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

I think the integral test works.

The taylor series of $\cos(x)$ is
$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k}$$

Thus, $$1-\cos(\frac1{\sqrt{n}})= -\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\frac1{n^{k}}$$

$$-\int^\infty_1 \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\frac1{x^{k}}dx=-\int^\infty_1 \sum^\infty_{k=2} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\frac1{x^{k}}dx+\int^\infty_1\frac{1}{2x}dx=C+\infty$$ where $C$ is finite.

Therefore the sum does not converge absolutely.

It is an elementary exercise to prove $C$ is finite.:)

Comment: After the first line, you assume taylor series is allowed? When I took Calculus II, taylor series was after convergence...

Comment: @BCLC I am not clear about the mathematics syllabus of foreign countries.

Comment: you seriously learned Taylor series first? In Stewart calculus Taylor series comes after right?

Comment: @BCLC Well, I learned things before the school taught me. I usually learn those stuff from MathSOS, here MathSE, or some documents showed up in Google search. I don’t really remember which should be taught first. Moreover, for some common entire functions, a student can use its taylor series directly. Using taylor series is easy when one does not have to understand it and care about its convergence.